# enable jquery click event based on PHP conditions

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, events, click

I'm trying to edit a wordpress template for a multi-video page.  Each video item can be clicked to play the video, however I want that click event enabled ONLY if a link is defined (in the wordpress shortcodes).  You can see an example of the video page here: http://madbunny.us/vixen/demo/all/dark/multi-video/

This is for a portfolio website, so having the image still as an item, but without a video is very important for me, if there is no link.

UPDATE:
After I tweaked it based on Jay Hewitt's reply, it does what I want, but it introduced a new problem, it can go to the next video, but won't go back to the previous video that doesn't have a url (click event disabled).

```
jQuery('.multivideo-center-play-btn, .multivideo-preview').each(function(){
    var _self = jQuery(this);
    _self.bind('click',function(){
        if(_self.parent().find(".hidden-url").text() != ""){
            var $vid = jQuery(this).parent();
            if ($vid.hasClass('active') || isAMobile)playVideo($vid);
            else moveToVideo($vid);    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is that what you are trying to do ? : if('<?php echo $content ?>' != ""). Are you in a .js file or a .php file ?

Comment: can't you check if the URL is defined with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the $content variable?  It looks like it will use that one variable for all bindings.

If it's just the URL set in the hidden-url div, then you want to add the binding to each selector meeting your criteria.

```
jQuery('.multivideo-center-play-btn, .multivideo-preview').each(function(){
    var _self = jQuery(this);
    var $vid = jQuery(this).parent();
    _self.bind('click',function(){
        if(_self.parent().find(".hidden-url").text() != ""){
            if ($vid.hasClass('active') || isAMobile){
                playVideo($vid);
            } else {
                moveToVideo($vid);
            }
        } else {
            moveToVideo($vid);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to rearrange the else parameter since the slideshow wasn't working at all.  It does exactly what I want, but now the slideshow won't go back to the video that doesn't have a URL, but will go next to a video that does have the URL.  I updated my code on the original post.

Comment: Ah OK, I've tested against your site, and updated my code snippet above.  This should do it for you.

Comment: Thank you soo much Jay!  This one has been bothering me for days!  Works perfectly, really appreaciate!

Answer (score 0):

set variables in php with something like this:

```
<?php
    if( $content ) {
        echo '<script>
                  var multivideo = true;
              </script>';
    }
?>
```

The, you can check in your script the defined variable.

Otherwiese, if you don't want to define a global variable, you can add `data`-attribute to the `.multivideo-center-play-btn, .multivideo-preview` element,
and check it with
`jQuery( this ).data( 'enabled' )`

Comment: Or set the URL as a data-attribute in the parent, that would be a nice solution

Comment: You mean because he defines $vid as buttons parent? This is actually not needed to do, because calling `jQuery(this)` or `$vid` is closely the same without the fact that vid has already taken some space in cache and can be used to keep the performance high. Because in a big application it will cause performance lags, to call jquery everytime you want to do something with elements than save them in variables :)